# get real string from client to server vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, parsing, client-server

```
listener = New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, portconnect)
    listener.Start()
    client = listener.AcceptTcpClient
    loginInfo = receivedata()
    Dim array() As String
    array = loginInfo.Split("|")
    username = array(0)
    pass = array(1)
```

Info client send to server is logininfo. I slipt logininfo into username and password.

```
Public Function authentication(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String) As Boolean
        Dim authentica As Boolean = False
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "  data source= " & Application.StartupPath & "\" & dataName

        Dim myCommand As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
        Dim sqlstr As String = ""
        sqlstr = "Select password from tbusers where Username = " & "'" & user & "'"
        myCommand.CommandText = sqlstr
        con.Open()
        Dim passw As String
        passw = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        con.Close()
        If pass = passw Then
            authentica = True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return authentica
End Function
```

Problem is: `If pass = passw Then authentica = True End If`
Allways return false.
Please help

Comment: No bro, I think, when client send data, data is encapsulated. Debug, user is username and newstr ="username". the boolean user = newstr , it return false

Comment: Please show what code you have already that is not working

Answer (score 1):

If the pipe character '|' always separates the user name and password, split on that:

```
Dim str As String = "username|password"
Dim splitString() As String = str.Split("|")
Dim userName As String = splitString(0)
Dim password As String = splitString(1)
```

As you mentioned if the length of the username differs (as it most likely will!) you will need something constant to be the basis for the split.

But you are better off separating the username and password anyway so they can be accessed independently.

Comment: This is not my problem bro.

Comment: What isn't your problem? If what I've provided does not suit, update your question and provide some code to show what is not working as has been suggested already.

Comment: When you check for pass = passw have you seen if the values are the same in the debugger? Could be an issue with whitepsace or case sensitivity

Comment: Pass and passw same value when i debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Split function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
Dim str as String = "username|password"

Debug.writeline("Username is " + str.Split("|"c)(0))
Debug.writeline("Password is " + str.Split("|"c)(1))
```

This seems like a bad idea to send these in this way. For example: what happens if the password contains the pipe character?

Comment: Then again, aren't special characters normally not allowed in passwords?

Comment: Problem is Logininfo server receive is correct. I get username and pass correct too. but when i check length pass, its value is 8185.????????????? i dont unserstand why